# Parametros de una funcion en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function sumar(a,b) {console.log(a+b)}
```

Mi duda es si existe una manera de referenciar los parámetros con un `array/objeto` primitivo de `javascript`, para que en vez de hacerlo como en el ejemplo anterior, hacerlo de esta manera:

```
function sumar(a,b) {console.log(param[0] + param[1])}
```

En realidad lo necesito para otras funciones, pero para simplificar y facilitar el entendimiento de mi duda recurrí a estos ejemplos.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

Usa [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) en tu función para representar un número indefinido de argumentos como un array:

```js
function sumar(...param) { 
    console.log(param[0] + param[1]) 
}

sumar(1,2)
```

Ten en cuenta que hay otra forma usando el objeto **argument** pero la propia [documentación recomienda](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) que en código moderno, deberías usar **rest parameters**.

> Nota: Si estás escribiendo código compatible con ES6, entonces se deben preferir los [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).